# Tailwind css v3.0.24 is not working in react app

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Tailwind css v3.0.24 is not working in react app.I have followed all the steps given in the official tailwindcss website but still not working.I have updated my react-script version even after that it is not working.

Here is my code.

tailwind.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

src/index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-portfolio-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: This happened to me sometimes. Just restart you react app and apply some color and you will see the changes

Comment: @TeshAych Still not working

Comment: can we have a video call and fix it?

Answer (score 3):

maybe you forget to import index.css to App.js

```html
import './App.css';
import './index.css';
function App() {
  return (
    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I was'nt the problem.Actually tailwind css was not showing in package.json file as devdependencies .

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json` does not show `tailwindcss` is installed as dev **devDependencies** remember to includes `index.css` in your `App.js`

```sh
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Comment: Earlier when i executed the command still it wasn't showing tailwindcss in devdependencies in package.json file but when i created new react app from tailwindcss website following the same procedure it works.